# If $a\leq b$ and $-a\leq b$, then $|a|\leq b$.

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

I have arrived at the two separate conclusions:

1. $a\leq b$
2. $-a\leq b$

Can I conclude that $|a|\leq b$? I am missing something as it is not by definition of the absolute value.

Comment: Yes, because one possible definition of the absolute value is $\;|a|=\max(a,-a)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is! Since $\lvert a\rvert$ is one of the numbers $a$ or $-a$, and since both of these numbers are smaller than or equal to $b$, $\lvert a\rvert\leqslant b$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your conclusion is correct; just note that $\max(a,-a)=|a|$.

Answer (score 3):

You could prove it by proving the contrapositive, as follows.

Assume $|a|>b$.

Now $|a|=a$ or $|a|=-a$.

Therefore $a>b$ or $-a>b$.